# Babel 'of' keyword (as in "Page x of y")

Tags: macros, babel

I want to have "Page X of Y" in the footer, but I also want it to be flexible for other languages. I know I can do

```
\providecommand{\pagename}{Page}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
...
\pagename
```

which will display `Seite` instead of `Page` because of babel. What I want is something similar to `of` so that I can write:

```
\pagename \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}
```

with the appropriate macro instead of `of` so that when I switch to german (or any other language), the `of` will also switch to the appropriate language.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\providecommand{\pagename}{Page}
%\usepackage[german]{babel}

\fancypagestyle{custom}{%
    \fancyhf{}% clears the footer and header
    \fancyfoot[c]{\pagename \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
}%

\pagestyle{custom}

\begin{document}

foo baz baa, this is a document

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Then we know exactly what you are doing, exactly which class and which packages.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such feature in `babel`, there might be in the `translator` package. But if your document is only in German one might as well just hardcode it.

Comment: I do not think I really need an MWE, because I am asking for a specific macro provided (hopefully) by babel. This is supposed to be a template that others can use, so I am not going to be using this in exclusivley one language.

Comment: you can add such translations with various packages (including babel) or with own code, but you would have to create the translations yourself for every language that you want to support.

Comment: You always need an MWE as the solution depends on the class and packages used.

Answer (score 1):

With `babel` you have `\setlocalecaption`, which can be used to both redefine existing `\...name` captions and define new ones. The suffix `name` is added automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,italian,ngerman]{babel}

\setlocalecaption{english}{of}{of}
\setlocalecaption{italian}{of}{di}
\setlocalecaption{ngerman}{of}{von}

\begin{document}

\pagename\ 1 \ofname\ 4.

\selectlanguage{english}

\pagename\ 1 \ofname\ 4.

\selectlanguage{italian}

\pagename\ 1 \ofname\ 4.

\end{document}
```

This prints:

> Seite 1 von 4.
> Page 1 of 4.
> Pag. 1 di 4.

Answer (score 0):

I defined a new macro that has this property: `\of`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N\g_of_text_prop
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_of_text_prop
 {
   english   = {of},
   spanish   = {de},
   german    = {von},
   italian   = {di},
   norsk     = {av},
   nynorsk   = {av},
   swedish   = {av},
   danish    = {af},
   french    = {de},
   esperanto = {el}
 }
\newcommand{\of}
 {
   \prop_get:NVNTF \g_of_text_prop \languagename \l_tmpa_tl
     { \l_tmpa_tl }
     { \prop_item:Nn \g_of_text_prop {english} }
 }    
  
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

So now I can write:

```
\pagename \thepage{} \of\ \pageref{LastPage}
```

and when I use `\usepackage[german]{babel}`
I get: "Siete 1 von 1", as I wanted.